# How to start tomcat service on Ubuntu restart

Tags: command-line

I have installed tomcat on Ubuntu system. I need to configure tomcat service such that it starts on Ubuntu machine is started.

Answer (score 5):

Start the Tomcat service by executing:

```
sudo systemctl start tomcat
```

Check the service status with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

OUTPUT:

> ```
> ⬤ tomcat.service - Tomcat 9 servlet container
>   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-09-05 15:45:28 PDT; 20s ago
>  Process: 1582 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> Main PID: 1604 (java)
>    Tasks: 47 (limit: 2319)
>   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
> ```

If there are no errors **enable the Tomcat service to be automatically started at boot time:**

```
sudo systemctl enable tomcat
```

To allow traffic on port 8080 type the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
```

[Here are all steps](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: +1 and edited your code blocks. Note though for `systemctl status` I don't think you need to prepend `sudo` to the command. Only when changes are being made.